# Find the value of lambda for which the error term is negative

Tags: calculus, analysis, geometric-series

I consider the following error term where $\lambda\in(0,1)$. I want to find the value of $\lambda$ for which it is negative

$$
\lambda^{n-1} -2\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\lambda^k
$$

We have that

$$
\lambda^{n-1} -2\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\lambda^k = \lambda^{n-1} -2\lambda^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda^k = \lambda^{n-1} - 2\frac{\lambda^n}{1-\lambda} 
$$

This to be negative implies

$$
\lambda^{n-1} < 2\frac{\lambda^n}{1-\lambda}\implies 1-\lambda < 2\lambda\implies \frac{1}{3} < \lambda 
$$

I think that my computation is correct, but I should find that it works for $\lambda$ close enough to $1$, which is not the case here ?

NB : close enough is not very precise but it is the word use in the exercise..

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: If $\lambda >1/3$ then it includes values of $\lambda$ close to $1$. This seems fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for your comment !